# How to use Active Model Serializer without an Active Record Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plpgsql, pg, active-model-serializers

I want to take the results of a pl/pgsql function, that returns a set of records and user AMS to serialize the results.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AMS can [serialize a Plain-Old Ruby Object](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/serialize_poro.md).  AMS provides `ActiveModelSerializers::Model` which can easily make a PORO a serializable object by doing this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :id, :name, :level
end
```

MyModelSerializer would be the default serializer.

Comment: Up to date docs: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#what-does-a-serializable-resource-look-like

Comment: I also followed the docs of AMS and tried to do the same but Rails fails to find the serializer: `[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with User (0.09ms)`.  My `UserSerializer` looks the same as your `MyModel`; What am I missing ? Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/127a7e45104c27791f90daef01fab6c8) to describe it better.